# Inscribed pentagon with four equal sides

Tags: geometry

[Inscribed pentagon with four equal sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI1wG.png)

Let ABCDE be a pentagon inscribed in a circle of radius r.
Let AB=BC=CD=DE=a and AE=b.
Find the radius r as a function of a and b.
I faced this problem as a partial problem on the snub cube solution (vertex figure).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Let $\angle BOC = x$. Then in triangle $BOC$
$$\frac{\frac a2}{r}=\sin \frac x2$$
$\angle AOE=2\pi-4x.$ Then in triangle $AOE$
$$\frac{\frac b2}{r}=\sin \left(\frac {2\pi -4x}2 \right)=\sin\left(\pi-2x \right)=\sin 2x$$
$$\begin{cases}
a=2r \sin \frac x2
\\
b=2r \sin 2x
\end{cases}$$
We obtain a system of equations with two equations and two unknowns

$$\frac ba=\frac{\sin2x}{\sin \frac x2}=\frac{2\sin x \cos x}{\sin \frac x2}=\frac{4\sin \frac x2 \cos \frac x2\cos x}{\sin \frac x2}=4\cos \frac x2\cos x$$
$$\cos \frac x2\cos x=\frac{b}{4a}$$
$$\cos \frac x2\left(2\cos^2 \frac x2 -1\right)=\frac{b}{4a}$$
Let $\cos \frac x2=t$
$$2t^3-t=\frac{b}{4a}$$
Let $t_0$ be a solution of equation $2t^3-t=\frac{b}{4a}$. Then $\sin \frac x2=\sqrt{1-t_0^2}$
$$r=\frac a{2\sqrt{1-t_0^2}}$$